# attempt to index field 'icgnn' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, torch

here's the code i am using:

```
local IcgResample, Parent = torch.class('icgnn.IcgResample', 'nn.Module')

function IcgResample:__init(inter_method, height_factor, width_factor, antialiasing)
  Parent.__init(self)

  if inter_method then
    self.inter_method = inter_method 
  else 
    error('you have to specify an interpolation method')
  end

  self.height_factor = height_factor or 2
  self.width_factor = width_factor or height_factor

  if self.height_factor <= 0 or self.width_factor <= 0 then
    error('factors have to be > 0')
  end

  if antialiasing then 
    self.antialiasing = true
  else
    self.antialiasing = false
  end
end 

function IcgResample:updateOutput(input)
  input.icgnn.IcgResample_updateOutput(self, input)
  return self.output
end 

function IcgResample:updateGradInput(input, gradOutput)
  input.icgnn.IcgResample_updateGradInput(self, input, gradOutput)
  return self.gradInput
end
```

i met the error which is the title.i'm new to lua,and i am rush to run this code,anyone knows how solve the problem?
i have print the input,which is a cudaTensor.
icgnn is a module.

Answer (score 0):

The proglem is that input *doesn't* have an icgnn field.  That error is telling you that you are trying `somevariable.icgnn.someproperty`, but that `somevariable.icgnn` is nil.  'indexing' refers to trying to access a property on the named field: [codepad sample](http://codepad.org/ppisvlmj)

```
local variable = {}
variable.exists = {}
print(variable.exists.message) -- fine
print(variable.icgnn.message)  -- error, trying to index field icgnn that is nil
```

Comment: i think icgnn is a module.what i am confused is why not use icgnn.IcgResample_updateOutput(self,input) instead of input.icgnn.IcgResample_updateOutput(self, input)

Comment: I think this must be a torch thing, is that what is calling `function IcgResample:updateOutput(input)`?  Can you find out where that is called and what it is passing as 'input'?

Comment: input is a cudaTensor, and IcgResample_updateOutput is realised by c language.i can't find out where that is called.